# why didn't I get my app on the tablet

Tags: android

I have an app and I want it to appear on tablets that don't support a SIM card so I've done:

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true" ></supports-screens>

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission 
          android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
          android:required="false"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
            android:required="false" />
```

But still it didn't appear what could be the problem?

Comment: did u get any errors on logcat

Comment: @Pearl that's very short sighted of you. This has nothing to do with logcat.

Comment: no it just work fine on all the devices but not the tablet with no SIM Card

Comment: for tablet which layout folder you have created?

Comment: I have same layout for all the screens but just changed the values folder values-large values-normal values-small

Comment: try with values-xlarge..

Comment: I also have a values-xlarge folder

Comment: is it showing any message or error while installing to tablet?

Comment: it doesn't appear in the play store of the tablet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to this is problem related to Telephony.

Set telephony to be optional in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for your application:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

May this will work fine for your application.

Comment: do you mean : <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
            android:required="false" />

Comment: ok thanks and is there a similar one to the vibrate? or it's the same?  android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"

Comment: I think Vibration is supported by all the android devices and tablet so it doesn't create any issue for appear..